# Data saved samples down when recording a rosbag

Tags: ros, rosbag, rosbag-record

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to save RGB and Depth images from 5 different sensors and as well record a rosbag from them. When ever I try to record he rosbag, the number of images saved drops from 30Hz to 7 Hz. Without the rosbag, it looks fine. How can I handle this situation?

Should I try recording rosbag in a different system or should I selectively sample the data saved in rosbag?
Any ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259647/data-saved-samples-down-when-recording-a-rosbag/) by [Joy16](https://answers.ros.org/users/27343/joy16/) on ROS Answers with karma: 112 on 2017-04-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should do some investigation to find the reason for the slow-down first. There are several possible causes, including the settings you are using to record the bag file (do you have compression turned on? Run your nodes and rosbag, and see how much CPU time is being used by each relevant process) and whether the quantity of data coming in is too high for your hard disc (use dd or the Disk Utility/gnome-disks in Ubuntu to see if your hard disc is fast enough). Recording on another system is a possible solution but then you need to consider if the network bandwidth is enough for all that data.

It would help to know your system's specifications and what your data is like. How big are the images?

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2017-04-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0